# que tengo que hacer para que me pida volver de jugar?

Tags: while

```
Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean salir = false;
int opcion; 

while (!salir) {

    System.out.println("1. Tablero 4 x 4");
    System.out.println("2. Tablero 6 x 6");
    System.out.println("3. Salir");

  try {

       System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");

        opcion = menu.nextInt();

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion de tablero 4x4");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion de tablero 6x6");
                break;

            case 3:
                salir = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Solo números 1 y 2");
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
        menu.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al finalizar el `switch` haces la impresión de pantalla para volver a jugar si la opción es la de salir en el `if` que está debajo haces que salir sea `true` para que según tu `while` deje de ejecutar ya que un `true` negado es falso.

```
while (!salir) {

    System.out.println("1. Tablero 4 x 4");
    System.out.println("2. Tablero 6 x 6");
    System.out.println("3. Salir");

  try {

       System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");

        opcion = menu.nextInt();

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion de tablero 4x4");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion de tablero 6x6");
                break;

            case 3:
                salir = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Solo números 1 y 2");
        }

        System.out.println("1. Volver a jugar");
        System.out.println("2. Salir");
        System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
        op = menu.nextInt();

        if(op != 1)
           salir = true;
        else
           salir = false;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
        menu.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: podrias explicar un poco esto a simple vista veo el mismo codigo

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag Al finalizar el switch haces la impresion de pantalla para volver a jugar si la ocipcion es la de salir en el if que esta debajo haces que salir sea true para que segun tu while deje de ejecutar ya que un true negado es falso

Comment: no fui yo el que pregunto , pero edita tu pregunta y pon esto

Comment: @DavidGarcia **No** añadas información extra a una respuesta como un *comentario*. [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/162978/edit) las veces que sean necesarias. No obligues a los usuarios a leerse una lista de comentarios para entender tu respuesta.

Comment: @Juanjo gracias, de hecho acabo de incursionarme en stack

Comment: @DavidGarcia Bienvenido. Se nota ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer tu programa más eficiente y que valide muchas cosas.

**Pimero**, el `try-catch` no es una buena idea para este ejercicio. Su uso se reserva para otros escenarios.

**Segundo**, en tu caso la mejor opción es el `do-while` ya que deseas mostrar el menú y preguntar por una opción al menos UNA VEZ. Es decir, necesitas ejecutar el código al menos UNA VEZ sin importar qué. Aquí entra el `do-while`. Con este ciclo aseguras que tu código obligatoriamente se ejecute al menos en una ocasión y la evaluación se hace después de la primera ejecución del ciclo.

**Tercero**, debes validar que el usuario solo ingrese números. Qué pasaría si el usuario ingresa letras o alguna otra cosa?. Aquí puedes hacer uso de `do-while` también pero, como queremos validar siempre que el dato ingresado sea número entonces, en este caso es mejor usar `while`.

Ejemplo (he comentado todo):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int opcion = 0;
        boolean salir = true;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ciclo do-while
        do {
            System.out.println("1. Tablero 4 x 4");
            System.out.println("2. Tablero 6 x 6");
            System.out.println("3. Salir");

            // Validar que el dato ingresado sea un número
            do {
                System.out.print("Escribe una de las opciones: ");

                // Mientras sea diferente a un número
                // Ciclo while
                while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("\nError, tu respuesta no es un número!\n");
                    scanner.next();
                    System.out.print("Escribe una de las opciones: ");
                }

                // Finalmente, guardar el número y salir del ciclo
                opcion = scanner.nextInt();
            } while (opcion <= 0);

            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion de tablero 4x4.\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion de tablero 6x6.\n");
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Programa finalizado...");
                salir = false;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("\nError, opción inválida!\n");
                break;
            }

        } while (salir);

        // Cerrar Scanner
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.